# Typical IMU accelerations and angular velocities for lower limbs

Tags: mechanical-engineering, sensors, biomechanics

Is there a dataset out there right now that shows the typical acceleration and angular velocity values for sensors attached to the thigh, shank, and feet for standard walking?

Or literature/textbook that describes what these typical values should be?

Comment: Some sports analysis? cycling performance, running?

Comment: Sorry, I meant with typical walking performance, also running if it is available

Comment: Made the comment as a hint for where you might start looking.

Answer (score 0):

You could ballpark this in about 5 minutes by downloading an accelerometer logging app on your phone and duct taping it to various parts of your body.

Comment: Are you assuming that the OP is average or typical?

Comment: Within an order of magnitude, yes.